# Legendre Transform

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm doing Legendre Transform, but I'm not sure if the result is correct.
So I have $$f(x)=\frac{x^\alpha}{\alpha}$$
With the formula $$f^*(p)=px(p)-f(x(p))$$ I found:
$$f^*(p)=p^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}-\frac{p^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}}{\alpha}$$
so if we pose$\beta=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha -1}$, we find:
$$\frac{p^{\beta}}{\beta}$$
What do you think about what I did?
Any suggestions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate

Comment: So normally this function is not convex, we have to find the convex cojugate